# Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.InvalidMetadataException : Could not resolve member reference

Tags: c#, teamcity, fxcop

I am running a team city build, which is failing continuously because of FXCope unable to resolve the reference.

Getting following error:

> The following error was encountered while reading module 'project': Could not resolve member reference: [dllNamespace, Version=1.0.0.238, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]dllNamespace.IoC::Setup.

The actual version of the dll is `1.0.0.238` and it is present in the teamcity build and all my tests are getting passed but at the end of the build Fxcope throw the above error.